# Google Voice: There was an issue refreshing your inbox?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, google-voice

Using Android 2.2.1 (Version.2.3.340.MB810.Verizon.en.US) on a Droid X.  I just updated Google Voice to version 0.4.2.34 yesterday and now I continually get an error message that appears as a notification:

```
Google Voice
There was an issue refreshing your inbox
```

Clicking on the notification takes me to Google Voice settings.  I have powered off my phone and turned it back on and the behavior persists.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the app data?

Answer (score 4):

From Al Everett's comment, I decided to try signing out of the application (which gives a warning about deleting all data) and signing back in, figuring that would be a less extreme step than going to manage applications clear data (although maybe it does the same thing). It seems to have fixed the problem

Comment: I had to clear app data to fix this.  HTC Espresso (T-Mo MyTouch slide)

Answer (score 1):

All I did was go to `menu | settings | applications | Google Voice` and selected <kbd>Force Stop</kbd>. It cleared the issue without deleting the data.